# What is the standard way to make a post call with empty request data angular 5?

Tags: angular, rest, http

`body` is a compulsary parameter in `HttpClient's` `post` method in angular. So to achieve my purpose I have to either send the body as null or empty quotes. But in that case I would need a corresponding method on server side rest api also with an argument. I was looking for a way not to have any argument in my server side method. What is the best approach to achieve this ?

Comment: http.post(url,{}) this is what I do

Comment: Do I need an argument in rest api method for this ?

Comment: I think you need to change the title of this question - a post call requires a body, even if, as you say, that is null/empty quotes. So the answer to your question title is "Not possible". It seems your question is more about the server side, not angular.

Comment: done, thanks for pointing my question is related to angular since I was searching for a way to do in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `body` parameter is mandatory for the post ([Angular's POST documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)). When your http request doesn't need a body the common approach is to use a `GET` request